# Install CA with mkcert on local DDEV site with non-sudo user

Tags: ddev, cacerts, mkcert

I am running a Mac with Ventura and a non-admin ("normal") user account. I have access to an admin user which is how I installed DDEV and mkcert with homebrew. However, I can not run `mkcert -install` to create a local CA with my normal user for my project without a sudo password, which I don't have and am not allowed to get. Any ideas?

```
normal-user$ mkcert -install
Created a new local CA 
Sudo password:
```

`normal-user` is not in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in my particular case there seems to be no way to run `mkcert -install` on MacOS with a user that does not have sudo access. I was able to get my IT dept to temporary enabled admin privs for my normal user, which allowed me to run `mkcert -install` successfully.

I can confirm that after the initial install was run, even after the admin privs were revoked, I could spin-up additional DDEV projects with HTTPS with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have adequate permissions you can probably install the CA directly into your browser instead of into the system store.

One set of answers is at https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-add-a-trusted-certificate-authority-certificate-to-chrome-and-firefox/

Give that a try. It may also be limited by your permissions. You can find the mkcert CA location using the command `mkcert -CAROOT`

Comment: I tried everything here. I cannot move or import certs made with the admin user to the normal-user. On macos all certs including browsers are managed by the Keychain. When I try to import the cert into my "Local Items" I get the error:

`"An error occurred. Unable to import “mkcert dwattsadmin@ral-venus (DWatts Admin)”.

Error: -25294"`

Comment: I think you'll need to talk to your IT folks, perhaps get them to do the `mkcert -install` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get temporary admin privs enabled for my normal user to run `mkcert -install` and all went smoothly. I can also confirm that after the initial install, even after the admin privs were revoked, I could spin-up additional projects with HTTPS with no problem.